# Microsoft Outlook email subject - how to stop auto hyperlinks?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to stop email clients like Microsoft Outlook to stop creating hyperlinks in the email subject? I know we can stop them for email body, but I need to make them stop in the subject line as well.
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks,
Natalia

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-format-or-delete-a-hyperlink-HA102011388.aspx#_Toc275417900 This might help?

Comment: Does it create a hyperlink or does it just view one? There's a difference, especially with non-outlook clients, they might not view it as a hyperlink. You can check the message source of such an email if you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting... It should be in File/Options/Mail/[Spelling and Autocorrect]/[Autocorrect Options] then untick under [Autoformat] and [Autoformat as you Type] the 'Internet and network paths with hyperlinks'.

Yet it doesn't! One to throw at Microsoft i would suggest! :)